# mpld3 dynamic updates from js

Tags: mpld3

Just starting out with `mpld3`. Trying to dynamically modify lines + points + patch from the `js` side.

I have been working with this example (without much success) https://mpld3.github.io/examples/heart_path.html. What I'd like is to be able to change the graphic entirely on mouse interactions. Specifically, I'm trying to continuously display the convex hull.

I can write the chull algorithm but what I cannot seem to figure out is how to modify the graph. Just really stuck at the moment. For context, I don't have too much UI experience.

Thanks.